# SoapUI - Automatic client generation with custom headers in request methods

Tags: java, web-services, soap, soapui, soap-client

I need to add custom headers into my requests to a web service soap.

Using SOAPUI (with axis2) I have created the client application (Java) that invokes a Web Service.

Autogenerated methods does not give the opportunity to add custom headers to the requests.
But I need to update my client application by adding client-side SOAP message some custom headers to these autogenerated request methods.

So, I've added this to my wsdl:

```
<soap:Header>
    <header1>value1</header1>
    <header2>value2</header2>
    <header3>value3</header3>
</soap:Header>
```

And tried again to generate client code. Unfortunately it didn't work, my methods still don't give me the ability to add headers.

Is it possible to do this automatically using SOAPUI? Maybe with some option while setting client code generation...

I hope I've been clear in explaining the problem.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why are you shouting in the title?

Comment: didn't noticed caps lock